# PostgreSQL Backup Batch file not working

Tags: postgresql

I have the following batch file/script to backup a PostgreSQL database on a Windows 2012 server which works fine on two servers I have running. On the new server, it works but prompts me for the password. I recall I had the same problem on the other two servers but don't recall what I did to make it work some 4 years ago. Can someone help? I have searched all over including here and have not found the solution yet. I did not write the script. I was passed on to me some 4 years ago

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM The next line sets the following DayTime variables: DT_Day, DT_DayOfWeek, DT_Hour, DT_Minute, DT_Month, DT_Quarter, DT_Second, DT_WeekInMonth, DT_Year
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic.exe Path Win32_LocalTime GET * /value') do (for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set DT_%%b)
for %%a in (DT_Month DT_Day DT_Hour DT_Minute DT_Second) do (if !%%a! LSS 10 set %%a=0!%%a!)
set Timestamp=%DT_Year%%DT_Month%%DT_Day%_%DT_Hour%%DT_Minute%%DT_Second%
echo Timestamp: %Timestamp%
set PGPassFile=%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
REM database/PostgreSQL Information
SET PRODDB=database_name
SET PGUSER=username
SET PGPASS=password
SET PGHOST=localhost
SET PGPORT=5432
SET PGBIN="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin"
SET BACKUPEXT=backup
SET BACKUPDES="C:\Backups"
IF not exist %BACKUPVER% (mkdir %BACKUPDES%\%BACKUPVER%)
REM formats can be custom/plain/tar
SET FORMAT=custom
SET GLOBALS=globals-%Timestamp%.sql
SET BACKUPFILENAME=%PRODDB%.%Timestamp%.%BACKUPEXT%
for %%a in (%PGPASS%) do (>"%PGPassFile%" echo %PG_HOST%:%PG_PORT%:%PRODDB%:%PGUSER%:%%~a)
@ECHO Backing up globals to %GLOBALS%...
%pgbin%\pg_dumpall -U %PGUSER% -p %PGPORT% -g > %BACKUPDES%\%GLOBALS%
@ECHO Backing up %PRODDB% to %BACKUPFILENAME%...
%pgbin%\pg_dump -U %PGUSER% -p %PGPORT% --format=%FORMAT% -C %PRODDB% > %BACKUPDES%\%BACKUPFILENAME%
REM del "%PGPassFile%"
```

Comment: Does the specified as the PGPassFile value exist?

Comment: Is your `pg_hba.conf` file the same for each server?

Comment: Yes, I have compared the pg_hba.conf file with the working server and have added the same entries on the new server that did not exist already.

Comment: @fooquency I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean the row 
`set PGPassFile=%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`
Please explain.

Comment: Might well be a `pg_hba.conf` problem. Did you run `pg_ctl reload`? What does the file look like?

Answer (score 0):

So it was a problem with the ph_hba.conf. I had identical entries on a working server and the new server. It did not work. I copied the pg_hba.conf file from the working server to the new server. The backup/pg_dump script is running now without prompting for a password.

Strange